# Does the pin count

Tags: bowling

If I bowl my first ball and there are two pins but they’re wobbling and the gate comes down and one pin Falls before the pinsetter comes down. Does that pin count?

Answer (score 2):

If the pin is wobbling because of the ball or another pin striking it and the pinsetter itself did not assist, then it is a legal pin.  Since you say the pin falls before the pinsetter comes down, that seems to fit this situation.

If the pinsetter did touch the pin, then the pin would not count.

See [USBC Rules](https://bowl.com/getmedia/00b3ea52-567e-43d6-b93a-e26d83d1b5bb/Rulebook-23-24.pdf) 6a and 6b for legal and illegal pinfall situations.  Nothing in your question seems to suggest that one of the illegal situations occurred, so it should be a valid pin.

Comment: Having just re-read the question, I'm not sure this is the situation the question refers to: "one pin Falls **before** the pinsetter comes down" (my emphasis).

Comment: Yes, I agree.   I think I also did not read it completely....